# Plural of 'head of agency'

Tags: grammatical-number

What is the plural of 'head of agency'? 'Heads of agency', 'head of agencies', or 'heads of agencies'?

Comment: This really depends on how many heads there are per agency.  And how many agencies.  So, all of your examples are correct, depending on the numbers involved.

Comment: Are they all heads of the same agency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can only be one head. There may still be a chain of deputies (wielding similar power in the head's *absence*) but that's besides the point.

Hence, when you say *heads* you mean heads of respective entities (usually one for each, but the same person can *head* multiple entities sometimes).

When there is not enough context, the best fit would be "heads of agencies". Check the second example below. It is still possible that two (or more) ministries are headed by the same person.

ODO:

> **[head](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/head)** *noun*
>   4. A person in charge of something; a director or leader.
>
> ‘the head of the Dutch Catholic Church’
>
> ‘What other elected politician can you find asking direct, unflinching
>   questions to heads of government ministries?

Comment: I disagree that there can only one head. I know of several agencies which have co-chairpersons, with equal power and equal authority.

Comment: I agree, but all such co-chairpersons will still report to one person who is the actual _head_ of the _agency_. There may still be separate heads for individual departments/divisions within the agency.

Comment: Not necessarily.  The instances I had in mind were ones where the coz cars were not responsible to a single "head"; in one case they were both the founding members of organizations there was no higher authority.

Comment: In that case, I guess we don't call them _heads_ of the agency. Maybe we call them _leadership team_. Also, for regulatory compliance, there can only be one head even if that means officially naming one of the equal partners a _ceremonial_ head like CEO/MD. I don't know of a company with multiple CEOs, do you?

Comment: Well, the two consuls in the Roman republic could be seen as two heads (of state), but apart from that, who says they have to be heads at the same time? Maybe John is head of agency X now, but Paul and George are former heads of the agency.

Comment: @oerkelens, thank you for opening my eyes. Now, how did I miss this point?!

Answer (score 1):

As Pete says in his comment, they can all be correct.

If John is head of agency X, and Paul is head of agency Y:

> John and paul are the heads of the agencies.

If John is head of agency X and he is also head of agency Y:

> John is head of the agencies.

If John and Paul together are heading agency X:

> John and Paul are the heads of the agency.

If we don't know or mention the agencies involved, the definite article before *agency / agencies* is dropped. So if we just describe what their job or function is, we can say:

> John and Paul are heads of agencies.
>   John is head of agencies.
>   John and Paul are head of agency.

Those three sound a bit off though, and that may be because many speakers will probably opt for *agency head* as a base, where *agency* is used attributively to modify *head*. In that case *agency* does not get pluralized, so when referring to John and Paul, we can say they are *agency heads*.

Comment: I agree entirely with this.  Adding a "the" to each of the last examples, and "both" to the last might impart some sense, I think.  If they're formal job titles, then capitalising might help.